# Swift ios check which viewcontroller is present

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I wonder how I can check what view controller that is currently displayed.

When a user recivies a notification and press on it I want to take the user to a certain VC. But only if the user is not already there.

I am using this when I get a notification:

```
if let tabBarController = self.window!.rootViewController as? CustomTabBarController {
                        let navInTab:UINavigationController = tabBarController.viewControllers?[0] as! UINavigationController
                        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                        let destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EventVc") as? EventsViewController
                        navInTab.pushViewController(destinationViewController!, animated: true)

                        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
                    }
```

I dont want to run this code if the user already is in **EventVc**

Also, can I run the code above if the user already is in **tab 0** but in a different VC than EventVc?

And if it is any help my app is built like this:

(root) TabBar

(tab1) -> navigation controller -> vc -> vc...

(tab2) -> navigation controller -> vc -> vc...

(tab3) -> navigation controller -> vc -> vc...

(tab4) -> navigation controller -> vc -> vc...

Comment: did my answer solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

this function should solve your problem, just send **index** number as an argument *(forexample: 0 for tab1, 1 for tab2 etc.)* at it navigates you `selectedIndex` `ViewController`.

```
// Navigation TabIndex TabBar View Controller
fileprivate func goTabIndex(index: Int) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "yourTabbarStoryboardID", bundle: nil)
    let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EventVc") as! UITabBarController
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = index
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(tabBarController, animated: false)
    }
}
```

You can find the **Presenting ViewController** like this;

```
let presentingVC = self.window?.rootViewController?.presentingViewController
```

**Presented ViewController;**

```
let presentedVC = self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController
```

[image]